# How to combine multiple p-values into one?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value, combining-p-values

I have the data of 841 genes along with the p-values which represents the association of that gene in a particular tissue (Aorta in this case) with some diseased phenotype. I want to combine the p-values of these 841 genes into a single p-value. The idea is that, this single p-value (after combining all the p-values of the genes) will represent the significance of the tissue in the particular phenotype. I have tried using the fisher.method command as below

```
fisher.method(pval, method = c("fisher"), p.corr = c("BH"), zero.sub = 1e-05, na.rm = FALSE, mc.cores = NULL)
```

The output looks like this:

```
     S num.p p.value     p.adj
1    3.332016528     1 0.18900 0.9830678
2    1.623861433     1 0.44400 0.9830678
```

I was expecting a single p-value as a result of combining all the p-values. But in this case I am getting the p-value and adjusted p-values for all 841 genes.  Moreover, the column p-value in the output is exactly the same as the p-values in the input file? In short, I can't interpret the output correctly or maybe I am doing it all wrong. Can anyone elaborate it please?

Comment: Can you give us some more info about these 841 p-values? How did they get calculated? What do they represent exactly? Does each gene "interact" with the tissue and produces "X" and these p-values is the Hypothesis testing H0: μ(x) = 0 and H1: Otherwise

Comment: Try using the metap package from CRAN and look for the sumlog() command. Disclaimer: I am the author of that package. Alternatively e-mail the maintainer ofthe unnamed package you are using and ask them what their package does.

Comment: The package appears to be `metaseqR` with documentation [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/metaseqR/man/metaseqR.pdf).  I suspect your input matrix or table is not what the function expects for your purposes.